# want to create app with frontend angular 2 need suggestions on backend to create rest api

Tags: spring, angular, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am planing to build an application using frontend language angular 2 and Application need to have oauth authorisation and consume rest api, i have knowledge about spring so is it good to integrate angular with spring? And any library that would easy the task of authorisation?

Comment: dot net core !!

Comment: Well, even when this question seems to be very open to give a good answer, let me suggest that if you already have experience with certain stack, try to use it (unless you want to build something to have some practice with it).

Comment: @germanio can u suggest me some library to ease the process of authorisation.

Comment: have you checked this out? http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/

Comment: @germanio ya i have gone through it i need some api that would handle my authorisation part such as storm path api, firebase

Comment: @Adibrajiwate are you sure this is not what you are looking for? https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ (sounds like a Jedi, but I'm not haha)

Comment: I recommend Java with Spring and Hibernate for databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REST API typically should be built agnostic regarding which front end will be using it. Since it will be stateless and is meant to be a common interface any modern back-end should be fine.

I am not as familiar with Spring but I imagine it will have everything you are searching for. Similarly NodeJS and .NET or .NET core would be equally sufficient alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with php using CURL.